# Criar executáveis em python (portabilidade)

Tags: python, windows, compilação, osx

Tenho código python desenvolvido em sistema MacOs. É possível gerar executáveis para rodar em outros sistemas (windows, linux)?

Exemplo:

> o arquivo `file.py` foi escrito e testado em sistema MacOs, mas quero gerar um executável para rodar no windows: `file.exe` a partir do sistema da Macintosh. (vice-versa)

QUESTÃO:

Como realizar esta tarefa sabendo que não disponho de sistema windows na
máquina, e o objetivo é criar um `.exe` no MacOs ?

Já conheço o `Py2Exe`, `Py2App` e o `cx_Freeze` (entre outros), mas eles não resolvem o problema, já que precisaria do sistema windows para gerar o `.exe`

Espero não ter sido confuso!

Comment: Isso que você busca é uma [**compilação cruzada**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilador_cruzado) (compilar na plataforma X gerando um executável pro ambiente Y). Não sei te dizer se existem compiladores cruzados do Mac pro Windows, mas sugiro começar sua busca por aí (a menos que alguém sugira algo mais diretamente numa resposta).

Comment: P.S. Veja [essa pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2950971/520779). Ela se refere à compilação cruzada do Linux pro Windows, mas como o Mac OSX também é POSIX, talvez funcione pra você.

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Bom, para gerar um executável .exe, vc vai precisar tem um sistema operacional windows, que eu saiba não tem jeito.

Mas, uma coisa que vc pode fazer é instalar uma máquina virtual Windows ou usar o BootCamp, um software (nao testei) que instala junto com seu Mac o Windows (clique [aqui](http://mactutoriais.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/atualizacao-tutorial-boot-camp.html) para o site de um tutorial dele). Mas claro, só faça isso se a necessidade de um executável windows for muito grande mesmo.

Abraço!