# como compilar um script python em um executavel

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, .exe

Qual a melhor forma de compilar um script em python para um executavel que rode em um sistema operacional linux(ubuntu), windows e mac.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Criar executáveis em python (portabilidade)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100405/criar-execut%c3%a1veis-em-python-portabilidade)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Windows você pode compilar scripts Python .py em executáveis .exe usando o Pyinstaller junto com o PyWin32:

Segue aqui os links dos downloads:

Pyinstaller: https://www.pyinstaller.org/

PyWin32: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases

Você vai baixar o Pyinstaller zipado, basta estrair a pasta dele, e coloca-la dentro da pasta do Pyhon.

O comando pra compilar é o seguinte: (Onde tem os ... você coloca o diretorio completo de onde esta a pasta do Python, Pyinstaller, exemplo: C:\Python3\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller.py)

python C:...\pyinstaller.py script.py

Você também pode compilar online nesse seguinte site: http://py2exe.org/

Comment: e para linux, tem alguma maneira?

Comment: Para gerar apenas o binário utilize o parâmetro -F, ex: `$ pyinstaller -F script.py`
Quanto ao sistema operacional, para gerar um .exe, você precisa fazer a compilação no Windows, para gerar um binário(Linux) precisa fazer essa compilação em algum distro Linux, e o mesmo para MacOS

Answer (score -2):

Usando linux você pode usar o terminal.

> python meuscript.py

É a forma mais básica, sem usar IDE. Pode ainda especificar a versão do interpretador. Aqui por exemplo eu uso

> python3 meuScript.py

Uma alternativa é usando o Jupyter Notebook onde você pode executar um scrip linha a linha e ir vendo os resultados.

Ou usando uma IDE mesmo.

Comment: Não é isso que ele quer. Ele quer empacotar em um único arquivo o script juntamente com os módulos e arquivos necessários para o programa rodar. Por exemplo para a pessoa não ter que instalar manualmente os módulos necessários para o programa rodar.

Comment: sim, é exatamente isso. Quero empacotar o programa para que o usuário final não precise instalar nada.